# How does power bi incremental refresh decide whether to partition by day, month or year?

Tags: powerbi

In the Incremental refresh exmaple below, how does power bi decide whether to partition the data by day, month or year?

And is there any place where I can see how it has partitioned the data?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's managed automatically:

> As whole periods close, partitions are merged. For example, if a
> one-day refresh period and three year historical store period is
> specified in the policy, on the first day of the month, all day
> partitions for the previous month are merged into a month partition.
> On the first day of a new quarter, all three previous month partitions
> are merged into a quarter partition. On the first day of a new year,
> all four previous quarter partitions are merged into a year partition.

[Advanced incremental refresh - Partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-xmla#partitions)

> And is there any place where I can see how it has partitioned the data?

Yes.  Through the XML/A Endpoint when the Dataset is in a workspace on a Premium Capacity (including Azure Power BI Embedded) or  Premium per User.

Comment: I guess another way is to monitor the query hitting the db during refresh via profiler or extended events.